# Can JMeter Assert on Throughput?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-maven-plugin

Is it possible to have a Maven/Jenkins build fail due to JMeter tests failing to achieve a specified throughput?

I'm tinkering with the jmeter-maven-plugin in order to do some basic performance tests as part of a continuous integration process in Jenkins.

One can set a Duration Assertion on a Sampler in the JMeter test to mark the sample as failed if a response time is over a certain threshold. What I'd like is to be able to fail a build (in Maven, or in the Jenkins job that triggers the Maven build) based on the total throughput for a test.

Is this possible with any existing plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible. You can use the [Jenkins Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) and the JMeter "aggregate report". With aggregate report you can write a CSV or XML file. You can search this file for your throughput with the Jenkins Text Finder Plugin and then you can mark the build as failed or unstable. Alternativly, you can use a BASH script to search the generated JMeter report file and return a non null return value. This will make your build fail.